# Configure Postfix to ignore bounce replies to an invalid sender address?

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to ignore bounces caused by a specific sender? We have a code repository server that sends emails to users/addresses for all commits. For some reason, it’s difficult to have invalid recipients (users that no longer exist) removed, so whenever messages are sent to such invalid users from e.g., notifications@server.example.net, they bounce. However, the Postfix server receiving the bounce cannot reach server.example.net (which doesn’t run a mail server anyway), so I’d prefer to just not generate bounce messages that would go to that address, since they just get queued and retried for 5 days before being dropped.

Comment: You can create transport rules that just sinkhole emails to certain destinations.  Once I'm at a computer i'll write an answer for this

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I've never had to delve into transport stuff, so I'll test it during normal hours tomorrow and follow up. Thanks!

Comment: Appears to work beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transport_maps` definitions to specify recipients and domains to which you simply want to discard.

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, make sure you set this:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

Create the file `/etc/postfix/transport_maps` with the following:

```
server.example.net    discard:
```

You can have as many lines as needed with as many domains, targets, etc. that need discarded to.  You can also have full addresses such as `someone@example.com` instead of full domains.

Whenever you modify your transport maps file you need to then run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport_maps` and then restart or reload your postfix service.